# htaccess rewrite changing url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm having trouble connecting the dots here. Is there an in between step for changing the url within the .htaccess. This is what I have so far. 
        moniquetrinidadjewelry.com/necklace/product.php?id=17&product_name=enchanting%2520pearl

and the rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$necklace/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/$ product.php?id=$1&product_name=$2
```

My goal and what I believed to be set as above is  a url of moniquetrinidadjewelry.com/necklace/id/product_name

I'm not entirely sure where the issue is coming from. There is no change within the address bar at refresh, reload or a start over of browse.(ie. home necklace> ect.)

Am I missing something important or have I skipped a step not within the htaccess itself?

Edit:

```
# Use PHP5.3 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53s .php

# Always use www in the domain
# Replace 'moniquetrinidadjewelry' with your domain name
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+)?moniuetrinidadjewelry.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://www.%1moniquetrinidadjewelry.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)&product_name=([a-zA-Z]+)$
RewriteRule product.php necklace/%1/%2/

# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options -MultiViews +FollowSymlinks
Options -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine on

# Always use www in the domain
# Replace 'moniquetrinidadjewelry' with your domain name
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+)?moniuetrinidadjewelry.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://www.%1moniquetrinidadjewelry.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteRule ^/?(.*/?)index\.(htm|html|php) /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

ErrorDocument 404 /

<Files error_log>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

# Ultimate htaccess Blacklist 2 from Perishable Press
# Deny domain access to spammers and other scumbags
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ADSARobot|ah-    ha|almaden|aktuelles|Anarchie|amzn_assoc|ASPSeek|ASSORT|ATHENS|Atomz|attach|attache|autoema    ilspider|BackWeb|Bandit|BatchFTP|bdfetch|big.brother|BlackWidow|bmclient|Boston\     Project|BravoBrian\ SpiderEngine\ MarcoPolo|Bot\     mailto:craftbot@yahoo.com|Buddy|Bullseye|bumblebee|capture|CherryPicker|ChinaClaw|CICC|clip    ping|Collector|Copier|Crescent|Crescent\ Internet\     ToolPak|Custo|cyberalert|DA$|Deweb|diagem|Digger|Digimarc|DIIbot|DISCo|DISCo\     Pump|DISCoFinder|Download\ Demon|Download\     Wonder|Downloader|Drip|DSurf15a|DTS.Agent|EasyDL|eCatch|ecollector|efp@gmx\.net|Email\     Extractor|EirGrabber|email|EmailCollector|EmailSiphon|EmailWolf|Express\     WebPictures|ExtractorPro|EyeNetIE|FavOrg|fastlwspider|Favorites\     Sweeper|Fetch|FEZhead|FileHound|FlashGet\     WebWasher|FlickBot|fluffy|FrontPage|GalaxyBot|Generic|Getleft|GetRight|GetSmart|GetWeb!|Get    WebPage|gigabaz|Girafabot|Go\!Zilla|Go!Zilla|Go-Ahead-    Got-It|GornKer|gotit|Grabber|GrabNet|Grafula|Green\ Research|grub-    client|Harvest|hhjhj@yahoo|hloader|HMView|HomePageSearch|http\     generic|HTTrack|httpdown|httrack|ia_archiver|IBM_Planetwide|Image\ Stripper|Image\     Sucker|imagefetch|IncyWincy|Indy*Library|Indy\     Library|informant|Ingelin|InterGET|Internet\ Ninja|InternetLinkagent|Internet\     Ninja|InternetSeer\.com|Iria|Irvine|JBH*agent|JetCar|JOC|JOC\ Web\     Spider|JustView|KWebGet|Lachesis|larbin|LeechFTP|LexiBot|lftp|libwww|likse|Link|Link*Sleuth    |LINKS\ ARoMATIZED|LinkWalker|LWP|lwp-trivial|Mag-Net|Magnet|Mac\ Finder|Mag-Net|Mass\     Downloader|MCspider|Memo|Microsoft.URL|MIDown\ tool|Mirror|Missigua\     Locator|Mister\     PiX|MMMtoCrawl\/UrlDispatcherLLL|^Mozilla$|Mozilla.*Indy|Mozilla.*NEWT|Mozilla*MSIECrawler|    MS\     FrontPage*|MSFrontPage|MSIECrawler|MSProxy|multithreaddb|nationaldirectory|Navroad|NearSite    |NetAnts|NetCarta|NetMechanic|netprospector|NetResearchServer|NetSpider|Net\     Vampire|NetZIP|NetZip\ Downloader|NetZippy|NEWT|NICErsPRO|Ninja|NPBot|Octopus|Offline\         Explorer|Offline\ Navigator|OpaL|Openfind|OpenTextSiteCrawler|OrangeBot|PageGrabber|Papa\ Foto|PackRat|pavuk|pcBrowser|PersonaPilot|Ping|PingALink|Pockey|Proxy|psbot|PSurf|puf|Pump|        PushSite|QRVA|RealDownload|Reaper|Recorder|ReGet|replacer|RepoMonkey|Robozilla|Rover|RPT-    HTTPClient|Rsync|Scooter|SearchExpress|searchhippo|searchterms\.it|Second\ Street\     Research|Seeker|Shai|Siphon|sitecheck|sitecheck.internetseer.com|SiteSnagger|SlySearch|Smar        tDownload|snagger|Snake|SpaceBison|Spegla|SpiderBot|sproose|SqWorm|Stripper|Sucker|SuperBot    |SuperHTTP|Surfbot|SurfWalker|Szukacz|tAkeOut|tarspider|Teleport\     Pro|Templeton|TrueRobot|TV33_Mercator|UIowaCrawler|UtilMind|URLSpiderPro|URL_Spider_Pro|Vac    uum|vagabondo|vayala|visibilitygap|VoidEYE|vspider|Web\ Downloader|w3mir|Web\ Data\     Extractor|Web\ Image\ Collector|Web\ Sucker|Wweb|WebAuto|WebBandit|web\.by    \.mail|Webclipping|webcollage|webcollector|WebCopier|webcraft@bea|webdevil|webdownloader|We    bdup|WebEMailExtrac|WebFetch|WebGo\     IS|WebHook|Webinator|WebLeacher|WEBMASTERS|WebMiner|WebMirror|webmole|WebReaper|WebSauger|W    ebsite|Website\ eXtractor|Website\     Quester|WebSnake|Webster|WebStripper|websucker|webvac|webwalk|webweasel|WebWhacker|WebZIP|W    get|Whacker|whizbang|WhosTalking|Widow|WISEbot|WWWOFFLE|x-Tractor|^Xaldon\     WebSpider|WUMPUS|Xenu|XGET|Zeus.*Webster|Zeus [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you must first capture the query string parts in a `RewriteCond` and then use that in a `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)&product_name=([a-zA-Z]+)$
RewriteRule product.php necklace/%1/%2/ [R,L]
```

This rule will fire, when there's a URL `product.php?id=17&product_name=enchanting%2520pearl` and rewrite it to `necklace/17/enchanting%2520pearl`. The client is redirected and the browser bar should show the new URL.

If you want it the other way round, this one should work

```
RewriteRule necklace/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z]+) product.php?id=$1&product_name=$2
```

Comment: Hi Olaf Thanks for the quick response. I think I see what you're saying, but I stil lcan't seem to figure it out. I've tried both changing the product name to product_name(a-zA-Z...) and switched id as id is numbers and I thought that may have been the issue, but nothing. If this is successful the address of http://www.moniquetrinidadjewelry.com/necklace/id/product_name should in fact take me to the original correct? It is simply having no affect. I've added my overall ht access above to  include what you referenced.

Comment: @HireLogo I fixed `id` and `product_name` and added a redirect `R` flag. I tried explaining what is happening here. If this is not what you intended, let me know.

Comment: Hi Olaf Thanks again...This is exactly what I'm trying to do, but I'm not seeing anything happening. I've included it in my .htaccess and nothing happens. I feel like I'm missing something from the equation as I've yet to see any change witin the address on any previous attempts.