# How do I rewrite a URL to remove the GET request from it?

Tags: php, .htaccess

so I want to change the url

http://localhost/upload_image/?name=whatever

to

http://localhost/upload_image/whatever

How would I do this? I've been googling this issue and so far nothing is working.

Comment: Show your attempts as this is fairly straight forward.

Comment: You need this for your webserver:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

Comment: This is a pretty standard request, I answered similar questions, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15029934/1741542 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/16156010/1741542